# jQuery ajax POST request to apache PHP server not receiving data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, http

This js jQuery script is properly formatting the form data to an object and sending it to my PHP code.

```
$("#formSignup").submit(function(e){
    // Map the array into a properly formatted object
    var data = {};
    $.map($(this).serializeArray(),function(n, i){
        data[n.name] = n.value;
    });
    // Send the http request
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "api/signup.php",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response){
            //console.log(JSON.parse(response));
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function(err){
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit defaultly
});
```

However PHP is unable to receiving the data. `print_r($_POST)` will print an empty array and the values are not accessible. It's not getting a response from the wrong file either.

That is pretty weird considering that the XmlHttpRequest recorded by the mozilla dev console is clearly posting the JSON data.

[image: XHR]

[image]

Other questions have been answered by stating redirects made by the server. However I haven't done anything at all with these settings and I got post requests working on the same server with my own function a while back.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your PHP code?

Comment: @Nick There's nothing special about it. The $_POST variable is simply empty.

Comment: PHP can't decode JSON into `$_POST`. If you really want to send the data as JSON, you have to use `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))`

Comment: @Barmar alright so how should I send it to be able to receive it with the post variable?

Comment: Read the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `contentType` property from your `ajax` object.

To serialize data just use `$(this).serialize()`.

```
$("#formSignup").submit(function(e){

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // Send the http request
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
        url: "api/signup.php",
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        failure: function(err){
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit defaultly
});
```

After that you should be able to successfully see your data inside `$_POST` variable.

Comment: That's what i'd like to avoid

Comment: @JohanSundman If you need to read your data server side with php then it is the way to go. Server side you can do `json_encode()`.

Comment: When you use `type: "post"`, the data is not put in the query string, it's put in the POST data.

Comment: If it were in the query string you'd have to read it with `$_GET`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. Not sure why I said that... Thank you